# Retrieve Data Weekly

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

I just want to ask if there is a query which retrieve the data from the below table as the following:-

Every week i want to display the total money paid by the customer.So i want to do a weekly check on money for every customer.

```
Customer  |   Date      |Money|
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Jhon        2014-07-01    22
Ammy        2014-07-02    25
Jhon        2014-07-03    21
Josh        2014-07-04    28
Josh        2014-07-05    30
Ammy        2014-07-06    211
Jhon        2014-07-07    217
```

Thank you...

Comment: Also add your code, in which you have tried something

Comment: Basically you restrict the rows of a special week with the help of a `WHERE clause` and the date and time functions of MySQL. Then you group by the customer name and `SUM` up the money.

Comment: Ive tried this query for retreive data each month were $id is a value from a text box taken 

SELECT Customer,MONTH(Date), SUM(Money) as TotalPaid, FROM Customer Where MONTH(Date)={$id} GROUP BY Customer";


but what i need is that every weeks passes i want a query to display want to display the total money paid by the customer.

Comment: You've got to define begin and end of a week, so one can write a reliable query that returns the right data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it with `GROUP BY` and the `WEEK`function:

```
SELECT customer, WEEK(date) AS week, SUM(money) AS total
FROM table
GROUP BY customer, WEEK(date);
```

Here is the sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0754f/1

---

If you want it only for the **current week**, you can add a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT customer, WEEK(date) AS week, SUM(money) AS total
FROM table
WHERE WEEK(date) = WEEK(NOW())
GROUP BY customer, WEEK(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not Clear...I suppose you want to get one week data

```
SELECT sum(Money) as TotalPaid FROM yourtable
WHERE Date between date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK) and now();
```

If you need to get two weeks,use something like this

```
 SELECT 'last week' AS week, COUNT(*) AS rows 
FROM table_name
WHERE date_logged >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL  6 DAY 
  AND date_logged  < CURDATE() + INTERVAL  1 DAY
UNION ALL
SELECT 'previous week' AS week, COUNT(*) AS rows 
FROM table_name 
WHERE date_logged >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 13 DAY
  AND date_logged  < CURDATE() - INTERVAL  6 DAY ;
```

Comment: Ive tried this query for retreive data each month were $id is a value from a text box taken 

SELECT Customer,MONTH(Date), SUM(Money) as TotalPaid, FROM Customer Where MONTH(Date)={$id} GROUP BY Customer";


but what i need is that every weeks passes i want a query to display want to display the total money paid by the customer.

Answer (score 0):

Your `SQL` query should be like this:

**Update**

```
SELECT Customer, sum(Money) as TotalMoney from MoneyTable 
WHERE `Date` BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(), interval -1 WEEK) and NOW() group by Customer
```

Build a PHP script and run that query every week and do whatever you like to do with the data.

Now the question is how to run it every week?

If you are using linux, you can use the `cron` service. Set it up like this:

```
5 8 * * 6 php /my/script/location/script.php
```

If you are using windows, try the scheduler and run your script via a `bat` file or something.

Hope that gives you the idea. good luck!

Comment: Ive tried this query for retreive data each month were $id is a value from a text box taken 

SELECT Customer,MONTH(Date), SUM(Money) as TotalPaid, FROM Customer Where MONTH(Date)={$id} GROUP BY Customer";


but what i need is that every weeks passes i want a query to display want to display the total money paid by the customer.

Comment: @lodev09: You should add the customer column too.

Comment: why should the query be limited to a specified time? You answer was true if the CRON job executed the script permanently minute by minute, but, when the CRON job takes care of weekly-execution, a simple QUERY would suffice...

Comment: @MostafaTalebi This answer is a lot better than yours. Maybe not the schedule.

Comment: @MostafaTalebi It will not suffice because it will get all other money from previous dates.